# Im having problems with dynamically calling a method

Tags: c#

I'm trying to dynamically call a method that accepts either a string or null. Im trying to build a command line program and I would like the commands to be able to accept no or some number of arguments. Here's the code to call the methods :

```cs
public class Command {
   public static void Interpret(AST.Command Command) {
      if (Command.command != null) {
         typeof(Interpreter.Command).GetMethod(Command.command)?.Invoke(null, Command.args.ToArray());
      }
   }
   public static void quit(string? args) {
      System.Environment.Exit(1);
   }

   public static void info(string? args) {
      Console.WriteLine("MathDoer Info :\n\tVersion : 0.0.1\n\tBy : Wiazarr");
   }
}
```

It is my understanding that the question mark after the string in the method declaration allows the string to be null and thus making the variable null, and it works if I call the methods normally but not while calling it with the Invoke method. How can I fix this?

Comment: How do we reproduce your issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When calling by reflection, pass null *or* use [Type.Missing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.missing) to indicate a default argument. The argument  *count* still has to match.

Here's some bare bones code I used to reproduce your issue. Does this help?

```
internal class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.Title = "Invoke with Reflection";
        var method = typeof(Command).GetMethod("info");
        method?.Invoke(null, new object[] { "NOT NULL" });
        method?.Invoke(null, new object[] { null });

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

**Mock minimal**

```
public class Command
{
    public static void info(string? args)
    {
        if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(args))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Called null or empty");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Called with {(string)args}");
        }
    }
}
```

[image: screenshot]

---

**Default Value in C#**

After reading your comment, I wanted to mention that `?` the context of an argument means that a null value is *allowed*. This is different from having a *default* value.

This is easier to show with an `int` argument which ordinarily isn't nullable.

```
internal class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var method = typeof(Command).GetMethod("methodWithInt");

        // Without the '?' this will not compile
        Command.methodWithInt(null);

        method?.Invoke(null, new object[] { null });
        method?.Invoke(null, new object[] { 1 });

        // Without the '= 10' default value
        // this throws a runtime exception
        method?.Invoke(null, new object[] { Type.Missing });
    }
}    
public class Command
{
    public static void methodWithInt(int? args = 10)
    {
        if(Equals(args, null))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Called null.");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Called with {args}");
        }
    }
}
```

[image: int demo]

Comment: Yes, it does! Thank you very much kind stranger! I didn't even know C# had default values... anyway thank you for your time and knowledge!

Comment: Indeed, C# _does_ have default values! I edited my answer because this can be an important distinction when calling a method dynamically.